# Moving pie graphs within their plot area using coldfusion

Tags: charts, coldfusion, cfml

I am experimenting with graphs in cold fusion and have attached an example. I find the the pie chart is too far to the right such that the legend overlays it. I would like to move the pie to the left and if possible also rotate them 90 degrees counter clockwise.

Is this possible?

[image: example graphs]

Sample chart code;

```
<cfchart format="html" chartwidth="280" chartheight="225" pieslicestyle="solid" name="lilydale" title="Lilydale court allocation (%)" showlegend="no">
    <cfchartseries type="pie" serieslabel="#tv[3]# games">
    <cfchartdata item="L1" value="#lg[1]/tv[3]#">
    <cfchartdata item="L2" value="#lg[2]/tv[3]#">
    <cfchartdata item="L3" value="#lg[3]/tv[3]#">
    <cfchartdata item="L4" value="#lg[4]/tv[3]#">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

Comment: The CF UI tags like this are just wrappers around certain JavaScript libraries and could be difficult to get exactly what you want. You'd be better off just using a dedicated chart library and passing data to the code with CF. A couple of options: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/pie.html https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

Comment: Thanks for that link. Had a look at it, but it was a little above my skill level. Did some more research on the CFCHART parameters and found a solution. See Below.

Answer (score 2):

The CFCHART tag supports a parameter called PlotArea. This parameter supports a "struct of keys", which I could find very little about on searches. However, I did find one question someone asked that was not working.

I got it working like this:

```
plotarea='#{"margin-left":"0","margin-top":"10")#'"
```

This moved the pie chart more to the left. A small increase to 350 from 280 pixels in the chart width gave me enough clearance with the PlotArea values to get the charts looking the way I wanted.